Query the max total count of tickets sold
I want to find the cinema with the max total number of tickets sold:



Cinema
Date
OfficialSold




1
2024-07-28
10


2
2024-07-28
10


3
2024-07-28
20


4
2024-07-28
30


5
2024-07-28
20






Cinema
Date
RetailSold




1
2024-07-28
10


3
2024-07-28
5


5
2024-07-28
10


6
2024-07-28
30



The number of tickets sold in each cinema contains two parts: official and retail. If there is no ticket sales record for a certain cinema, it means 0.
I want to get the following output:



Cinema
OfficialSold
RetailSold
TotalSold




4
30
0
30


5
20
10
30


6
0
30
30



And I tried:
WITH CombinedTickets AS (
    SELECT
        o.Cinema,
        o.OfficialSold,
        r.RetailSold,
        (COALESCE(o.OfficialSold,0) + COALESCE(r.RetailSold,0)) AS TotalTickets
    FROM Official o
    LEFT JOIN Retail r ON o.Cinema = r.Cinema
), 
MaxTickets AS (
    SELECT 
        MAX(TotalTickets) AS MaxTotal
    FROM CombinedTickets
)
SELECT
    Cinema,
    COALESCE(OfficialSold,0),
    COALESCE(RetailSold,0),
    TotalTickets
FROM CombinedTickets
CROSS JOIN MaxTickets
WHERE TotalTickets = MaxTotal
ORDER BY Cinema;

But I got this answer, I don't know why there is no cinema 6. Could anyone provide a correct method?(If you don't know the database I use, you can use PostgreSQL instead, thanks!)



Cinema
OfficialSold
RetailSold
TotalSold




4
30
0
30


5
20
10
30




You don't get cinema 6 in your result because it appears in one of the two tables only. Therefore, the LEFT JOIN query doesn't fetch it.
I would prefer to use UNION ALL here to be sure to get all cinemas, no matter if they appear in the first, in the second or in both tables.
Then sum up the values from both queries, sort the result by TotalSold descending and fetch the first row with ties:
WITH combined AS
  (SELECT 
    cinema,
    officialsold,
    0 as retailsold
  FROM official
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    cinema,
    0,
    retailsold
  FROM retail)
SELECT c.* FROM 
  (SELECT
    cinema, 
    SUM(officialsold) AS officialsold, 
    SUM(retailsold) AS retailsold,
    SUM(officialsold + retailsold) AS TotalSold
   FROM combined GROUP BY cinema
   ORDER BY TotalSold DESC
   FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES) c
 ORDER BY c.cinema;

This will return as requested following result for your sample data:



Cinema
OfficialSold
RetailSold
TotalSold




4
30
0
30


5
20
10
30


6
0
30
30



You can verify this here: db<>fiddle
Note: You can remove the outer query with SELECT c.* if you don't need to sort the result by cinema.

SQL query I used have CTEs to pull together sales data from two tables: OfficialSalesTable and RetailSalesTable. First, it sums up the official sales by cinema in the OfficialSales CTE and does the same for retail sales in the RetailSales CTE. Then, it combines these results in the TotalSales CTE using a FULL OUTER JOIN, which ensures that all cinemas are included, even if they don’t have sales records in one of the categories. The COALESCE function is handy here, as it fills in any missing sales data with zeros. Finally, the query picks out the cinemas with the highest total ticket sales by comparing the TotalSold values. This method gives a clear and complete picture of which cinemas sold the most tickets.
 WITH OfficialSales AS (
    SELECT Cinema, SUM(OfficialSold) AS OfficialSold
    FROM OfficialSalesTable
    GROUP BY Cinema
),
RetailSales AS (
    SELECT Cinema, SUM(RetailSold) AS RetailSold
    FROM RetailSalesTable
    GROUP BY Cinema
),
TotalSales AS (
    SELECT 
        COALESCE(o.Cinema, r.Cinema) AS Cinema,
        COALESCE(o.OfficialSold, 0) AS OfficialSold,
        COALESCE(r.RetailSold, 0) AS RetailSold,
        COALESCE(o.OfficialSold, 0) + COALESCE(r.RetailSold, 0) AS TotalSold
    FROM OfficialSales o
    FULL OUTER JOIN RetailSales r ON o.Cinema = r.Cinema
)
SELECT *
FROM TotalSales
WHERE TotalSold = (
    SELECT MAX(TotalSold)
    FROM TotalSales
);


I believe you are expecting data from both the tables, if it exists in any of the table. if so here is the solution.
    SELECT 
ISNULL(A.CINEMA, B.CINEMA) AS Cinema,
ISNULL(A.OFFICIALSOLD,0) AS OfficialSold,
ISNULL(B.RETAILSOLD,0) AS RetailSold,
ISNULL(A.OFFICIALSOLD,0)+ ISNULL(B.RETAILSOLD,0) AS TotalSold
FROM CINEMA1 A

FULL OUTER JOIN CINEMA2 B
ON A.CINEMA = B.CINEMA

Results

You are using LEFT JOIN to form your table CombinedTickets but you table Official has no Cinema 6.  You may try to union and sum the to get the full CombinedTickets first
select Cinema, sum(office),sum(retail) from 
(
SELECT Cinema,OfficialSold ,0 RetailSold
  FROM Official 
  union
SELECT Cinema,RetailSold, 0 OfficialSold
  FROM Retail 
  ) a group by Cinema


To get the max result the following solution works fine. We will union the two tables data. And then we will find TotalSold records for each Cinema. Then we will show result for only maximum sells based on TotalSold. We are not going to use FETCH FIRST command in our solution.
WITH CombinedTickets AS
(
   SELECT Cinema, OfficialSold, 0 AS RetailSold
   FROM official
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Cinema, 0 AS OfficialSold, RetailSold
   FROM retail
)


Select * FROM 
(
   Select Cinema,SUM(OfficialSold) as OfficialSold,SUM(RetailSold) as 
   RetailSold,SUM(OfficialSold+RetailSold) as TotalSold 
   FROM CombinedTickets 
   GROUP BY Cinema
   ORDER BY TotalSold DESC
) as Result where
TotalSold = ( Select MAX(TotalSold) 
FROM (Select Cinema,SUM(OfficialSold+RetailSold) as TotalSold 
FROM CombinedTickets 
GROUP BY Cinema
ORDER BY TotalSold DESC
) 
)
ORDER BY Cinema


Thanks for your answer, but there is a little issue: subquery in FROM must have an alias. I use a as an alias.  WITH CombinedTickets AS
(
...
)
Select * FROM
(
...
) as Result where
TotalSold = ( Select MAX(TotalSold)
FROM (Select Cinema,SUM(OfficialSold+RetailSold) as TotalSold
FROM CombinedTickets
GROUP BY Cinema
ORDER BY TotalSold DESC
) a
)
ORDER BY Cinema

@Abdul Why do you want to avoid FETCH FIRST?

Added this as an alternative, cause FETCH do not work in older versions of database. It supports from PostgreSQL 8.4, Oracle 12c, MS SQL 2012, MySQL 8.0
